# Symfony : get object the form is based of

Tags: forms, symfony

Can you tell me how to get the object on which a form is based on from the Form object itself

exemple :

```
 $form = createForm(....., $objectForm);

 $form->handleRequest();
```

Let's say I want to get $objectForm from $form. is it possible ?

Comment: what do you mean with "Form Object itself"? Into EntityType?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're developing a custom *FormType*, then you can simply use
`$builder->getData()`; i.e. like this:

```
class ApplicationNetworkType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $object = $builder->getData();
    }
}
```

In your controller, however, you need to reference the `$form` instance:

```
$form->getData();
```

[Link 1](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_getData)

[Link 2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/forms.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could get it from options array:

```
class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $object = $options['data'];
    }
}
```